# How to get data from server to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node js i made this api:

```js
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    res.send('my data from server')
});
```

So, now, when i fetch data using:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:1000/user', {
    method: "GET",
 })
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

I expect in `console.log(data)` besides:

```js
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:1000/user", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:1000/user"
__proto__: Response
```

and:
data: 'my data from server', so at the end i expect something like this:

```js
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:1000/user", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
data: 'my data from server'
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:1000/user"
__proto__: Response
```

Question: Why i can not  get data from the server as i expect?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to extract the body.

> The Body mixin defines the following methods to extract a body
> (implemented by both Request and Response). These all return a promise
> that is eventually resolved with the actual content.

In your case its just a text, but it could also be JSON depends on what your server response.

```
fetch('http://localhost:1000/user', {
    method: "GET",
 })
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('http://localhost:1000/user', {
    method: "GET",
 })
   .then(res => console.log(res.body))
   .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Your data is inside res.body!!
(I have renamed data to res as it is kind of a standard)